# Unable to connect to Wifi - it

Tags: wireless, 16.04, wifi-hardware-switch

I am unable to connect to wifi after I upgraded to 16.04 Version.

Below is the wireless info. Please help me.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/16548090/

Comment: Try to disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings.